# Split string based on token

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to create a simple syntax checker as an add-in for Excel with C# to help to write correct queries for web applications like `TalkWalker` or `Pulsar`.

The kind of query they write are like the following:

> ("postmenopausal osteoporotic fracture" OR "postmenopausal
> osteoporotic fractures" OR ((menopaus* OR postmenopaus* OR
> perimenopaus*) NEAR/4 (fracture* OR osteoporos* OR vertebr* OR bone OR
> spine)))
>
> (PMO SENTENCE (fracture* OR osteoporos* OR vertebr* OR bone* OR spine
> OR spinal)) AND sourcecountry:uk

I created a procedure to identify the tokens in a string.

```
public class Tokenizer : ITokenizer
{
    private List<TokenDefinition> _tokenDefinitions;

    public Tokenizer()
    {
        _tokenDefinitions = new List<TokenDefinition>();

        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.And, " and ", 1));
        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.CloseParenthesis, "\\)", 1));
        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.OpenParenthesis, "\\(", 1));
        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.Quote, "\"", 1));
        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.Or, " or ", 1));
        _tokenDefinitions.Add(new TokenDefinition(TokenType.StringValue, "'([^']*)'", 1));
    }

    public Tokenizer(List<TokenDefinition> tokenDefinitions)
    {
        _tokenDefinitions = tokenDefinitions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DslToken> Tokenize(string lqlText)
    {
        var tokenMatches = FindTokenMatches(lqlText);

        var groupedByIndex = tokenMatches.GroupBy(x => x.StartIndex)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToList();

        TokenMatch lastMatch = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < groupedByIndex.Count; i++)
        {
            var bestMatch = groupedByIndex[i].OrderBy(x => x.Precedence).First();
            if (lastMatch != null && bestMatch.StartIndex < lastMatch.EndIndex)
                continue;

            yield return new DslToken(bestMatch.TokenType, bestMatch.Value);

            lastMatch = bestMatch;
        }

        yield return new DslToken(TokenType.SequenceTerminator);
    }

    private List<TokenMatch> FindTokenMatches(string lqlText)
    {
        var tokenMatches = new List<TokenMatch>();

        foreach (var tokenDefinition in _tokenDefinitions)
            tokenMatches.AddRange(tokenDefinition.FindMatches(lqlText).ToList());

        return tokenMatches;
    }
}
```

As result of this procedure, I have the list of token in the string.

[image]

Based on that, I'm looking for an efficient way to split to input string to analyze the text. For example, for this text

> ("postmenopausal osteoporotic fracture" OR "postmenopausal
> osteoporotic fractures" OR ((menopaus* OR postmenopaus* OR
> perimenopaus*) NEAR/4 (fracture* OR osteoporos* OR vertebr* OR bone OR
> spine)))

I expect to extract this list:

- "postmenopausal osteoporotic fracture"
- "postmenopausal osteoporotic fractures"
- menopaus*
- postmenopaus*
- perimenopaus*
- fracture*
- osteoporos*
- vertebr*
- bone
- spine

I'm trying to create my parser for that but it is a bit longer and I don't know if I'm considering everything. Is there common procedure and quite ready to use?

Comment: What is the name of that thing? What happens if you google for "X parser C#" ?

Comment: The name of what?

Comment: *"query they write"* - does it has a name? Specification? *"web applications like TalkWalker or Pulsar"* - tells me nothing. The example string you show contains `NEAR/4`, perhaps syntax of *that thing* is more complex and few moments later you will ask another question. I expect a parser is already written somewhere.

Comment: Apparently Pulsar is using Presto SQL. Grammar definition [here](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/antlr4/com/facebook/presto/sql/parser/SqlBase.g4) (ANTLR).